# Gmap3: How to add title to marker?

Tags: php, google-maps, jquery-gmap3

I have working php script that stores the name and address of the company in variables. I then echo it out like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#map").gmap3({
        marker:{
        address: "<?echo $coord;?>"
        },
        map:{
            options:{
                zoom:15,
                mapTypeControl: true,
                navigationControl: true,
                scrollwheel: true,
                streetViewControl: true
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How would I add the name of the company to show below the marker? For example: [this](https://www.google.co.za/maps/place/McDonalds+-+Kempton+Park/@-26.102362,28.232891,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x1e9514edb72dc921:0x2ecba331f1e54206)?

I tried to add:

```
marker:{
    address: "<?echo $coord;?>"
    title:   "<?echo $com_name;?>"
}
```

But this doesn't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The title property must be inside option property.

```
var marker = {
   latLng: [53.23564, 24.32654],
   data: 'some data',
   options: {
       title: 'Title',
       icon: '/Path/to/custom/icon/if/you/need.png'
   }
}
```

Other information you can show with infowindow.

Example:

```
        $(".gmap-widget .gmap3").gmap3({
            action: "addMarkers",
            markers: markers,
            marker: {
                events: {
                    click: function(marker, event, data){
                        var map = $(this).gmap3('get');
                        infowindow = $(this).gmap3({action:'get', name:'infowindow'});
                        if (infowindow){
                            infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            infowindow.setContent(data);
                        } else {
                            $(this).gmap3({action:'addinfowindow', anchor:marker, options:{content: data, maxWidth: 300}});
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```